# Get output of Netcat in Java

Tags: java, sockets, port, serversocket, netcat

I use this command on the terminal:

```
nc -l localhost 8080
```

and get this output:

```
GET /?code=Mdf81e469-fca0-f04e-db95-278aff0323be HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4
```

How can I get this output in a Java program?
All I need is the first line after the `GET`, so when I know how to get the whole output, I could easily get the `String` which I need.

Comment: This is is input to the server, not output from it.

Comment: I know, but I need the output that I get when I `nc -l localhost 8080` in the Terminal in a Java program.